# Quotient ring computation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Use the usual identification of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ with elements of $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. Let $F=\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle x^4+x^2+2 \rangle$. Every element in $F$ can be written uniquely as $a_0[1]+a_2[x]+a_2[x^2]+a_3[x^3]$ with $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}_5$. Given distributivity, all we need to be able to compute the product is to give the expressions for $[x^i][x^j]=[x^{i+j}]$ for $0 \leq i \leq j \leq 3$.
Compute $[x^4]$,$[x^5]$,$[x^6]$,$[1+2x^2+3x^3][4+2x+3x^2+2x^3]$.

I have since $[x^4+x^2+2]=I$, then $[x^4]=[x^2+2]$, $[x^5]=[x(x^4)]=[x(x^2+2)]=[x^3+2x]$, $[x^6]=[x^2x^4]=[x^2(x^2+2x)]=[x^4+2x^2]=[3x^2+2]$, and $[1+2x^2+3x^3][4+2x+3x^2+2x^3]=[58+28x+38x^2+31x^3]=[3+3x+3x^2+x^3]$. Am I correct? Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/844238/5798

Comment: It might be more intuitive to write "$[x^4+x^2+2]=[0]$ so $[x^4] = [4x^2+3]$".  This is not the same as "$[x+2]$", as you have written.

Comment: Formatting note: \langle and \rangle are what you want for the ideal (as I've edited in), rather than the less-than and greater-than signs.